# can't type my password in terminal

Tags: password, sudo, gnome-terminal

I am trying to install torrent, so I typed some commands like:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8:i386
```

after this command:

```
[sudo] password for shiddhant:
```

here is the problem comes, the cursor was only blinking, no input was accepted and nothing work then. So I have to close the terminal and I can't run torrent.

Comment: what do you mean by running torrent? what exactly are you trying to install?

Answer (score 1):

Password input is invisible in the terminal for security reasons. I think if you just type your password regardless and press enter it should work?